# Is there a way to make a serialized member to serialize as an attribute?

Tags: xml-serialization, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable, xml-attribute

Is there a way to make a serialized member to serialize as an attribute:

```
<Serializable> 
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

I want than when this class is xml-serialized, it should produce:

```
<Person Name="John Doe" />
```

And what I mean is that instead of the Name property should be serialized as an element, it should be serialized as an xml attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [XmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) attribute:

```
<Serializable()> 
Public Class Person
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()> 
    Public Property Name() As String
End Class
```

See more details and Xml-serialization attributes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I have another property Phones that is a List<string>, can I make the serialized xml strings to be <Phone>5555</Phone> rather than <string>5555</string>, or even <phone number="5555" />

Comment: I think you can, using the XmlElement attribute with the ElementName argument set to Phone. Open a new SO question if you don't succeed.

Comment: BTW, is your company recruiting by any chance? :-)

Comment: For some reason I thought you're employed at some software company. I'm a freelancer at the moment (about 60 minutes away from you :-) ). Anyhow, if you're willing to privately discuss some stuff, I'll contact you.

Comment: Yes, contact me.
Anyway, regarding the question I used the `XmlArrayItem`, it works for me. Thanks